# Go - HTML comments are not rendered

Tags: html, go, go-templates

I'm building go web application. I found some anomaly on the rendered html page. All of my html comments `<!-- -->` are suddenly not being rendered. My guess it's because the go version I used (just updated to higher version), because it was fine before I updated it.

This is my code:

```
<!-- prepare the breadcrumbs -->
<ul class="breadcrumb" data-bind="foreach: viewModel.breadcrumbs">
    <!-- ko if: ($index() + 1) < len(viewModel.breadcrumbs()) -->
    <li>
        <a data-bind="attr: { href: href }">
            <i class="fa fa-home"></i> 
            <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko if: ($index() + 1) == len(viewModel.breadcrumbs()) -->
    <li class="active" data-bind="text: title"></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

And this is the rendered page source:

[image]

Because of this issue, many of my KnockoutJS codes which are written using *containerless control flow syntax* goes crazy, it doesn't work at all.

What should I do to solve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a special type in the [`html/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) package: [`template.HTML`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#HTML). Values of this type in the template are not escaped when the template is rendered.

So you may "mark" your HTML comments as `template.HTML` and so they will not be escaped or omitted during executing your template.

One way to do this is to register a custom function for your template, a function which can be called from your template which takes a `string` argument and returns it as `template.HTML`. You can "pass" all the HTML comments to this function, and as a result, your HTML comments will be retained in the output.

See this example:

```
func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
        "safe": func(s string) template.HTML { return template.HTML(s) },
    }).Parse(src))
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, nil)
}

const src = `<html><body>
{{safe "<!-- This is a comment -->"}}
<div>Some <b>HTML</b> content</div>
</body></html>`
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/CT8EZEwDIO)):

```
<html><body>
<!-- This is a comment -->
<div>Some <b>HTML</b> content</div>
</body></html>
```

So basically after registering our `safe()` function, transform all your HTML comments to a template action calling this `safe()` function and passing your original HTML comment.

Convert this:

```
<!-- Some HTML comment -->
```

To this:

```
{{safe "<!-- Some HTML comment -->"}}
```

Or alternatively (whichever you like):

```
{{"<!-- Some HTML comment -->" | safe}}
```

And you're good to go.

**Note:** If your HTML comment contains quotation marks (`'"'`), you can / have to escape it like this:

```
{{safe "<!-- Some \"HTML\" comment -->"}}
```

**Note #2:** Be aware that you shouldn't use conditional HTML comments as that may break the context sensitive escaping of `html/template` package. For details read [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/8y6by6SERyU).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `text/template` instead of `html/template` and do all escaping manually using built-in functions such as `html` and `js` (https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Functions). Be aware that this is very error prone though.

Comment: I believe this has nothing to do with `mux`, you should change your handlers to use `text/template` package instead of `html/template`.

Comment: Downvoted: this is not so much "error prone" as *a major security risk* if you in any way use the template for what it's designed to do: inserting untrusted (or, at least, unescaped) data in the middle of a page