# Make a clickable div in Golang Template

Tags: javascript, go, templates, addeventlistener, go-gin

I would like to make a table where you can click on the rows using bulma and gin/gonic with golang.

----
I am familiar with Angular and other js frameworks that enable the ease of adding (click) event listeners and tying in a function.  I'd like to be able to add the equivalent of `(click)="doThisFunc()"`.  I'd also like to be able to use variables in class names like `class="{{isSelected}}"`

------

I would prefer to not use a javascript framework if there's a package in golang that would enable the same types of functionality in golang templates.

Please let me know of any packages/ideas/tips that you think would fit this type of capacity.

  Thank you!

this question does show the implementation of vanilla js into golang template and that may be what I need to learn, but I'm wondering if there's any easier way or a guide somewhere for this.
[Creating load more button in Golang with templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41136000/creating-load-more-button-in-golang-with-templates#41138344)


(p.s. if there's a way to embed a lightweight javascript framework like Solid, alpine, or svelte into a golang app without changing the go gin app much I'd also love to hear about that)

Comment: Why am I getting negative votes?  If you think it's a bad question then at least tell me why please.

Comment: Asking for library or tool recommendations is [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). See also [ask] for more advice on authoring a good question.

Comment: Would a better question be "tools or advice for implementing ui functionality in golang templates"?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "clickable", you probably need to use javascript, which is unrelated to Go templates. You can write `doThisFunc()` however you want, hooking into whatever framework you want, but there is not going to be a Go template solution to write this code for you.