# html file cannot work if {{ end }} is added

Tags: html, go, go-templates

I am using golang to add contents to the html template files. The main file is simple

```
func main() {
    server := http.Server{
        Addr: "localhost:8080",
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/process", processCover)
    server.ListenAndServe()
}

func processCover(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t1, _ := template.ParseFiles("t1.html", "t2.html")
    t1.Execute(w, "hello World")
}
```

In the html file, if I add the following code

```
<!-- {{ range . }}
<li>{{ . }}</li>
{{ end }} -->
```

The items after it are all missing. I don't get it because I think this is commented. It should be some bullet point I don't know about go web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML comments in templates are not rendered if the context of the output is HTML. Since you put your `{{range}}` in HTML comment (between `<!--` and `-->`) and since the output is an HTML document, it is stripped.

This is hinted in the doc of [`Template.Parse()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Parse):

> **A template definition with a body containing only white space and comments is considered empty** and will not replace an existing template's body.

See related: [Go - HTML comments are not rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348072/go-html-comments-are-not-rendered/34351058#34351058)

Comment: So do you mean because of the above reason you mentioned, all the items after this comment are skipped? Why couldn't it just skip the contents right in the comments?

Comment: I think the correct way to comment a template item is `{{/* */}}`, although it will miss from the browser.

Comment: @QiangYao if you want to produce output *with* HTML comments you can use custom template functions. https://play.golang.org/p/ZJMnjKk_XKK

Comment: @mkopriva I just happened to comment the template definitions for convenience, but yours is definitely a good trick to learn.